# asp.net label text changed at the client is not available at the web server end

Tags: asp.net, state

I am changing an asp.net label control's text using jquery at the client. But when I read it at the webserver ( C# code ), it shows me the value that was set in the UI (aspx). Is label text not a part of the control state?

Is there a way to force the label to be a part of the control state (the viewstate contains the values of the other controls like the textbox) ?

Comment: maybe you could use `if (!IsPostback)` before setting the text of the label at server side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Labels do not post their value back to the webserver. A label is basically span or label tag.**

You have to either store the change in a hidden textbox as well as in the label

or

Make a textbox appear like a label in styling so the value posts back.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try EnableViewState = true for this control?

Also - IMO - the label values are not part of the posted form collection items.

Why don't you put a hidden field on the form which contains the changed text from the label & then read it on the server side?

Comment: Please check with a hidden field rather than label changes on the client - that should be a simpler way to go...